# Twitter Bootstrap carousel not working, but has worked before

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I've created a website already that uses Twitter Bootstrap and everything works fine on it.
You can checkout the website [here](http://anytimetaxikona.com)!, it's the gallery page that uses the carousel feature.

I copy and pasted the same exact code I used for this website into my new one, the code is this:

```
<div class="carousel slide tac" id="image-gallery">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        {% for i, item in items %}
            {% set image = asset(item.getWebPath) %}
            <div class="item" id="item_{{ i }}">
                <img src="{{ asset(image) }}" alt="Silver Spoon">
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#image-gallery" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#image-gallery" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I've included the latest jQuery and the latest bootstrap.js.

I didn't even have to call $('.carousel').carousel() on my first website, I just gave it the right class. So I tried calling $('.carousel').carousel() but then it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'carousel'
```

Then the next thing I did was download the source files and I included carousel.js and transition.js while still including the whole bootstrap.js. And then this works.

But I'm wondering why my first website, the one that only needed to include bootstrap.js, works while my second website I have to include the extra carousel.js and transition.js.

Thanks ahead of time for any help!

Comment: include `data-ride="carousel"` in your `#image-gallery` div

Answer (score 0):

either include the `data-ride="carousel"` in your `#image-gallery` div or trigger carousel manually by writing javascript code `$("#image-gallery").carousel();` and also not to forget to include `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.css` in your code.